# microsoft edge, IE mode, not opening url in the same tab

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, window.open

im trying to open a url in IE mode in microsoft edge browser.

When a url is first opened I want it to open in a new tab in IE mode, and then use the same tab id for any future opening of the url.
but it doesn't. it always opens in a new tab.

the origin url is without IE mode.

without the IE mode , its working fine.

the code:

```
window.open("some URL", "tabId")
```

*I want that the url will be open in different tab than the current tab

does anyone knows if its possible or how to do it ?

thanks a lot

Comment: now your question asks for two different things, url to open in same tab and url to open in different type, could you please edit the question

Comment: You've confused us with "a new tab but the same tab". I don't know what that means.

Comment: Also, it's 2022. Time to abandon all aspects of IE, which was out of date half a decade ago.

Comment: Likely it’s a bug in the ie interop with the edge code. I doubt Microsoft would fix it

Comment: Do you want to open a url in IE mode from the origin Edge mode page? Do you configure the opening url in IE mode list? If not, I think you can't open an IE mode page from an Edge mode page using code. Besides, I see that you're using "tabId", are you developing an extension and using the [tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/)?

Comment: yes.I config my browser to open the specific given url in ie mode.
and no, I'm not developing extesion. I just want to open  link on spesific tab all the time. without IE mode the way to do it is to give ID to the opening  link

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. For now, it seems that there's no other workaround unless the origin and opening pages are in the same mode. I suggest that you can provide a feedback about this issue to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge. They will check the feedback and improve the product continuously. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "_self" name attribute for example

```
window.open("https://www.aurl.com","_self")
```

Comment: I want that the url will be open in different tab than the current tab

Comment: your question that you just edited asks for two different things, please edit it